# Classic steampunk anime where a woman fights multiple guards or henchmen on a moving vehicle

Tags: story-identification, anime, steampunk

Okay so, I definitely never saw the whole anime show or film but there is one scene that has stuck with me that I saw in a clip and I’m so desperately trying to re-find it.

What I can remember: a grenade or some kind of explosive is involved, a woman (pretty, definitely meant to be an adult) is fighting multiple guards or henchmen, she is making use of the fact that they are on a moving vehicle like a train or an airship. Lots of gunfire.

I’m pretty sure based on what I remember from the art style it is older/classical. Not dissimilar to *Lupin III* or other early Miyazaki’s, but I don’t think it’s them either.

I was definitely shown it in the context of this is an iconic/amazing scene, but I’ve had no luck in my search so far.

Any help you can give would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this, and did you watch it on TV or online? Also, do you recall the hair colour of the woman?

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! I watched it online, as a short clip without too much context, and unfortunately I don’t remember hair colour. Might have been dark, but I’m not certain.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] if you have questions. What aspect of this anime was sci-fi or fantasy?

Comment: My first guess would be Ghost in the Shell, but I can't recall a specific scene like that. You don't still have the clip, do you?

Comment: Ah sorry! Forgot to include that, it was kind of steampunky in vibe, which I thought was close enough but no worries if you want me to delete this question! Alas I do not still have the clip.

Comment: No worries, I've edited that in for you. If you have any more details to add you too can [edit] them in.

Comment: Aeon Flux, possibly?

Comment: Was she cooking hamburgers on a grill at some point of the chase? Any kangaroo-based super soldiers?

Comment: I haven't seen it, but does [Steamboy](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0348121/) ring a bell?

Comment: Could it be Aeon Flux? Dim memory there might be a fight on an airship, but no idea how to find it. Might jog someone's memory. There's also a [train fight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kbxq3_qDD5U) in Cowboy Bebop's Mushroom Samba episode, but the details don't really match

Answer (score 5):

You write that it's similar to, but *not* an early Miyazaki movie - are you sure of that?

Because it does sound like *Laputa: Castle in the Sky*, which is definitely steampunky, and features both car/train and airship battles involving the pirate leader Dola, who uses a kind of grenate launcher as weapon:

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately, I couldn't find videos of the fight scenes on Youtube, but the movie is available on Netflix.

Comment: Castle in the Sky is one of my favorite movies and I am almost certain this the answer.  Everything fits.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be [*"Kabaneri of the Iron Fortress"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabaneri_of_the_Iron_Fortress) (*"Kōtetsujō no Kabaneri"*)?

It's a short series (12 episodes) with a definite steampunk feeling: it is set in Japan after a zombie virus has all but destroyed the civilization, and the surviving humans live in fortified villages connected by railways, with armored trains being the only means of transport, communication and trade between the otherwise isolated communities.

The main female character is Mumei, a *kabaneri* (a person infected by the zombie virus, thus having great strenght and agility, but still preserving her human mind) that happens to travel on a train.
She is quite young (probably in her teens), so this element does not really match your description.

The series is relatively recent, being originally broadcast in 2016, but the character design could remind of older times.

There are numerous battles against the hordes of zombies using blades, firearms, steam-powered weapons and explosions, and often fought on the moving trains.
The opening sequence heavily features Mumei and her acrobatic fights: